# How can I implement hotkeys into my Discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am wondering how I might go about adding keypress detection to my Discord bot. For example, if I press `CTRL+1`, the Discord bot might execute a certain task in a certain channel.

One method I can think of achieving this is having 2 separate scripts. One that constantly listens to keystrokes and once a certain keypress combination is detected, it launches the Discord script with certain arguments. However, it would be preferable if I could do everything in the same file.

I have looked into keyboard libraries but there appear to be no obvious asynchronous solutions, and I'm not sure how I would go about creating one without blocking the Discord bot loop.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? Why can't you just use regular commands?

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak Maybe I should've mentioned, but the bot in question refers to a selfbot so it's not a server bot. It'd just be a lot more convenient if I could use hotkeys to automate stuff with my account (like deleting last 100 messages in the current open chat window when ```CTRL+1``` is clicked or exporting chatlog when ```CTRL+2``` is clicked )

Comment: @cat in case you didn't know, self bot are not allowed in discord. (doesn't mean you can't do it, it just mean you might get banned if you're caught)